# Force page refresh on link click in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my backbone.js app I want to be able to fire a simple link.

```
 <a href=/logout">Log Out</a>
```

Now I use it with router like this:

```
logout: function() {
  window.location = '/logout';
}
```

Is it possible to call this link straight from the html, just like a normal link? As a notice, the router has pushState enabled.

Comment: Have you tried just not defining this route?

Comment: Yes, the route in the browser is replaced, but not triggered

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question at the beginning. Check my updated answer

Comment: did you check with `return false` inside logout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the solution from backbone-boilerplate project - https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js#L22

Comment: I actually use this boilerplate, I add data-bypass as attribute to the a tag? Just tried it and it does not work

Comment: No, you should remove it because it works for all links that doesn't have `data-bypass` attribute :) `a[href]:not([data-bypass])`

Comment: Ok but it does not solve the problem, the link is just replaced in the   url bar but not fired

Comment: It should fire - `Backbone.history.navigate(href.attr, true)` second parameter is equals to `{trigger:true}`. http://jsfiddle.net would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is really about how you attach your events to the `<a>` tags. The simplest would be to add `rel="external"` to the links you don't want them to trigger backbone router. Something like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href][rel!="external"]', function(e){
    app_router.navigate($(this).attr('href'), {trigger: true});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And modify your HTML to be:

```
<a href=/logout" rel="external">Log Out</a>
```